# Multiple authors and their affiliations on Quarto Beamer presentation title slide

Tags: quarto, beamer

How can I list multiple authors and their affiliations on the title slide of a Quarto Beamer presentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try as following,

```
---
title: "Multiple authors"
format: beamer
keep-tex: true
author: 
  - John Doe\inst{1}
  - John Roe\inst{2}
institute: 
  - \inst{1} affiliation for John Doe
  - \inst{2} affiliation for John Roe
---

## Slide 1
```

---

[image: multiple authors with affiliations]

---

Though I think the above approach is the better one, but the following also works,

```
---
title: "Multiple authors"
format: beamer
author: 
   - John Doe$^1$
   - John Roe$^2$
institute: 
   - $^1$University 01
   - $^2$University 02
---

## Slide 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the Beamer template currently doesn't support the usual affiliations structure that other templates offer. Instead, the affiliations must be given in the `institute` field:

```yaml
---
title: "Test"
authors:
  - You
  - Me
institute:
 - ACME Corp.
 - Lorem Ipsum University
---
```

[image: Rendered result of the above example]